# I'm under the impression you need to register with Azerbaijani authorities within 15 days of entering the country. Is that at 23:59 on the 15th day?

Tags: georgia-country, e-visas, azerbaijan, registration

My evisa is actually for a 30-day period. However, I think I will only stay in Azerbaijan for 15 days, partly to avoid this registration process. I would prefer to leave at around 20:00 on the 15th day (December 21).

However, I entered Azerbaijan much earlier than 20:00 on December 6: I entered at 00:10.

Do I need to leave Azerbaijan before 00:10 on December 21, or do I need to leave before 23:59 on December 21?

Comment: Be careful with such ideas. The fact that you have to do it within 15 days (if you indeed have to) does not necessarily mean you don't have to do it if you stay less than 15 days. It could well be, most possibly, that you have to do it, period, and have to do so in 15 days or less.

Comment: At https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/azerbaijan/entry-requirements it says: "Registration
If you’re staying in Azerbaijan for longer than 15 days you must register with the State Migration Service within 15 days of arrival by either visiting the State Migration Service in person or online."

Answer (score 1):

As per [State Migration Service](https://www.migration.gov.az/en/oyq/oyq), indeed you need to register if you'll be staying in Azerbaijan for more than 15 days [1st¶]. You need to do this within 15 days of arrival [3rd¶].

Usually the time is not mentioned in official documents, so there's a chance they'll let you go.

But I think registration is quite simple. You just need to send an email to qeydiyyat@migration.gov.az [3rd¶] with the following documents [4th¶]:

> - [application form](https://www.migration.gov.az/content/pdf/sened4.doc);
> - Copy of the passport (other border crossing document) of the foreigner (including the visa page and pages indicating the last entry
>   to the country).

And it's free [5th¶].

Comment: I get the sense that the OP would prefer not to have to register, not that they think the registration process is onerous.

Comment: Totally valid preference by the way. Sadly, it's not clear from the text of the law, if times are taken into account or not, even when I read it in original Azerbaijani. Even if OP emails qeydiyyat@migration.gov.az from a throwaway email and gets an answer to their question, it will still be up to the random officer to interpret the text.

Comment: The alternative is to email from not-throwaway email and use it as evidence in case of a positive answer, but then it probably defies the whole point if OP doesn't like to leave lot's of papertrail.

Comment: @gdrt I assumed it would be time consuming. Could you provide a link to the page where you sourced the form from?

Comment: @novice Same page https://www.migration.gov.az/en/oyq/oyq

Comment: "application form" links to it. Also at the bottom of the page there are .pdf and .doc links

Comment: @novice Did you manage to leave on December 21 without registration? Or did you register after all?

Comment: @gdrt Due to being challenged in planning/organization, I didn't submit before 00:10 (instead whilst on the bus to the Red Bridge at ~19:00). I assume my form wasn't going to be processed at that time of evening, but I still thought it better to submit than not.) I was allowed through passport control at around 23:00, after which a border guard with camouflage had to scan the passport. The machine kept on flashing a warning signal (reading "STOP" I think) accompanied by an alarm, but he and his colleague decided to disregard the warning, I assume to let me off because it was before 23:59.

Comment: @novice Awesome. Glad you were able to cross the bridge.